# Fail message does not appear in form validation event

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to make a fail message which adds together different strings depending on the error on submit. However the fail message will not appear though the conditions are met.
I would like to know where is the error in my code. Thank you.

This is in an external JavaScript file which is linked to the HTML document.

```
 function validationEvent() {
    var flag = true;
    var alertmsg = "There were errors found in your registration:";
    var givenname = document.getElementById("gname").value;
    var surname = document.getElementById("sname").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("address1").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    var pcode = document.getElementById("pcode").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var cnum = document.getElementById("cnum").value;
    if (givenname == null || givenname == "") {
        alertmsg += " Given Name is a mandatory field.";
        flag = false;

    }
    if (surname == null || surname == "") {
        alertmsg += " Surname is a mandatory field.";
        flag = false;

    }
    if (address == null || address == "") {
        alertmsg += " Address is a mandatory field.";
        flag = false;
        }
    if (city == null || city == "") {
        alertmsg += " City is a mandatory field.";
        flag = false;
         }
    if (pcode == null || pcode == "") {
        alertmsg += " Postal Code is a mandatory field.";
        flag = false;
         } 
    if (email == null || email == "") {
        alertmsg += " Email is a mandatory field.";
        flag = false;
         }
    if (phone == null || phone == "") {
        alertmsg += " Phone Number is a mandatory field.";
        flag = false;
         }
    if (cnum == null || cnum == "") {
       alertmsg += " Credit Card Number is a mandatory field.";
        flag = false;
          }
    if (!vormCredit()) {
        alertmsg += " Visa Cards must start with 4 and Mastercard Cards must start with 5.";
        flag = false;

    }
    if (!stateCheck()) {
        alertmsg += " Invalid Postal Code.";
        flag = false;

    }
    if (!checkCredit()) {
        alertmsg += " Invaid Credit Card Number.";
        flag = false;

    }
    if (!flag) {
        alert(alertmsg);
         return false;}

    else {
        alert("Thank you for your subcription.");
        return true;}


    };
```

Edit: Removed 'return false' from the 'if' loops and added it only to the if(!flag) loop.

Comment: Don't call `return false` in your `if` statements. It will exit the function and stop it's execution. If there will be any error, your code will never reach the `!flag` condition because of the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the `switch` statement here. It handles the situation when you have more cases. Also you can use `break`.